# Problem with paste button on Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, button, contenteditable, paste, rich-text-editor

I have this problem: by following this [guide](https://gist.github.com/praveenpuglia/8ee8e5d7cd1f08a88ca3) I create two contenteditable div, each of which is connected with Rich Text Editor. They work great, but paste button don't.

How I can fix this?

Thank you in advance!